# ng-click="someFunction" coming through as ng-click=""

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following HTML element:

```
<re-button btn-type="primary" 
    re-permission="UpdateMaintenanceRequest" 
    ng-disabled="isSending || !model.IsCompanyEmailValid || !validSelection || sendEmailForm.ccEmail.$invalid" 
    ng-click="formOptions.save()" 
    id="send"
    ng-show="model.EmailType != 'QuoteRequestOwnerApproval'" 
    text="Send">
</re-button>
```

However when I inspect the element in Chrome, it comes through as:

```
<button class="btn no-transition btn-primary 
    ng-scope" btn-type="primary" 
    re-permission="UpdateMaintenanceRequest" 
    ng-disabled="checkDisabled()" 
    ng-click="" 
    id="send" 
    ng-show="model.EmailType != 'QuoteRequestOwnerApproval'" 
    text="Send" type="button">Send
</button>
```

Why is the button HTML code so different?

If `ng-click=""`, how is it possible that `$scope.sendEmail()` is still getting called (I used a breakpoint to make sure it's getting called).

I'm not a Javascript expert, but does it have something to do with the following code?:

```
$scope.formOptions = {
    beforeSave:function(callback){
        var selected = _.filter($scope.model.EmailContacts, {IsSending:true});
        if(selected && selected.length > 0)
            callback(true);
        else{
            callback(false);
        }
    },
    resource: function () {
        if ($scope.model.EmailType != $scope.emailTypeEnum.QuoteRequestOwnerApproval.Name) {
            return $scope.sendEmail();
        }
        else {
            return $scope.previewEmail();
        }
    }
};
```

**EDIT:**

Here is the `reButton` directive:

```
(function() {
    'use strict';

    angular.module('app.components')
        .directive('reButton', directiveFn);

    //directiveFn.$inject = ['context'];
    function directiveFn() {
        var directive = {
            restrict:'E',
            priority:100,
            scope:true,
            replace:true,
            template: '<button class="btn no-transition" />',
            compile:compileFn
        };
        return directive;

        function compileFn(tEle, tAttrs) {
            init();
            return postLinkFn;

            function init() {

                if (tAttrs.btnSize && tAttrs.btnSize !== '') {
                    tEle.addClass('btn-' + tAttrs.btnSize);
                }

                if (tAttrs.type) {
                    tEle.attr('type', tAttrs.type);
                } else {
                    tEle.attr('type', 'button');
                }

                if (tAttrs.btnType.indexOf('icon') < 0) {
                    if (tAttrs.text && tAttrs.text !== '') {
                        tEle.html(tAttrs.text);
                    }
                    else {
                        throw new Error('required text');
                    }
                } 
                else {
                    if (tAttrs.iconType === '' || !angular.isDefined(tAttrs.iconType)) {
                        throw new Error('Please provide icon type');
                    }
                }

                if (tAttrs.btnType) {

                    //if the icon attribute is not set then no need to put an icon html 
                    var iconTemplate = null;
                    if(tAttrs.iconType)
                    {
                        iconTemplate = '<span class="fa ' + tAttrs.iconType + '"></span>';
                        if (tAttrs.iconType && tAttrs.iconType.indexOf('icon-pt') >= 0) 
                        {
                            iconTemplate = '<span class="' + tAttrs.iconType + '"></span>';
                        }
                    }

                    switch (tAttrs.btnType) {
                        case 'primary':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-primary');
                            $(tEle).prepend(iconTemplate?(iconTemplate + '&nbsp;&nbsp;'):'');
                            break;
                        case 'link':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-link');
                            break;
                        case 'secondary':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-secondary');
                            break;
                        case 'cancel':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-cancel');
                            break;
                        case 'card-icon':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-icon card-icon');
                            $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
                            break;
                        case 'content-icon':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-icon content-icon');
                            $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
                            break;
                        case 'grid-icon':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-icon grid-icon');
                            $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
                            break;
                        case 'page-icon':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-icon page-icon');
                            $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
                            break;
                        case 'link-icon':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-icon link-icon');
                            $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
                            break;
                        case 'modal-icon':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-icon modal-icon');
                            $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
                            break;
                        case 'btn-icon-prepend':
                            tEle.addClass('btn-default btn-icon-prepend');
                            tEle.html($('<span></span>').html(tAttrs.text));
                            $(tEle).prepend(iconTemplate?(iconTemplate + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'):'');
                            break;
                        default:
                            tEle.addClass('btn-default');
                            $(tEle).prepend(iconTemplate?(iconTemplate + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;'):'');
                            break;
                    }
                }
                else {
                    throw new Error('require button type');
                }
            }

            function postLinkFn(scope, ele, attr) {
                var oriTitle = attr.title;
                attr.$observe('disabled', function(val) {
                    var titleDisabled = attr.titleDisabled;
                    if (val && titleDisabled) {
                        ele.attr('title', titleDisabled);
                    } else {
                        ele.attr('title', oriTitle);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }

})();
```

Comment: You are using a directive `re-button`, can you write it sources?

Comment: My guess is that it has something to do with the `re-button` directive, but without knowing what that directive is, I can't say for sure.

Comment: Could it be that your scope.sendEmail is in your form handler? because a button will trigger your form when clicked even with the ng-click not filled in.

Comment: @AndroidNoobie I've updated the question with the directive code.

Comment: I copy your code and play little bit with it, when click on button calls `save()` method from `$scope.formOptions`

https://jsbin.com/yegaroxoso/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: @MaksymPetrenko my code doesn't have a save() function defined in formOptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be due to a misunderstanding or misapplication of `scope` inside of AngularJS directives. Your directive has its own isolated scope. You could use the the `&` operator, which allows you to evaluate an expression on the parent scope of the directive. This essentially allows you to create a new attribute of the directive that will be used to specify what function to call.

Here's an example, using the directive code you posted. Note the changes to `scope` and `template` inside the directive code, and the addition of the `click-me` attribute on the `re-button` element in the HTML.

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

app.controller("MainController", function($scope) {
  $scope.save = function() {
    console.log("SAVE!");
  };
});

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('reButton', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      priority: 100,
      scope: {
        "clickMe": "&"
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<button ng-click="clickMe()" class="btn no-transition" />',
      compile: compileFn,
    }
  });

function compileFn(tEle, tAttrs) {
  init();
  return postLinkFn;

  function init() {

    if (tAttrs.btnSize && tAttrs.btnSize !== '') {
      tEle.addClass('btn-' + tAttrs.btnSize);
    }

    if (tAttrs.type) {
      tEle.attr('type', tAttrs.type);
    } else {
      tEle.attr('type', 'button');
    }

    if (tAttrs.btnType.indexOf('icon') < 0) {
      if (tAttrs.text && tAttrs.text !== '') {
        tEle.html(tAttrs.text);
      } else {
        throw new Error('required text');
      }
    } else {
      if (tAttrs.iconType === '' || !angular.isDefined(tAttrs.iconType)) {
        throw new Error('Please provide icon type');
      }
    }

    if (tAttrs.btnType) {

      //if the icon attribute is not set then no need to put an icon html 
      var iconTemplate = null;
      if (tAttrs.iconType) {
        iconTemplate = '<span class="fa ' + tAttrs.iconType + '"></span>';
        if (tAttrs.iconType && tAttrs.iconType.indexOf('icon-pt') >= 0) {
          iconTemplate = '<span class="' + tAttrs.iconType + '"></span>';
        }
      }

      switch (tAttrs.btnType) {
        case 'primary':
          tEle.addClass('btn-primary');
          $(tEle).prepend(iconTemplate ? (iconTemplate + '&nbsp;&nbsp;') : '');
          break;
        case 'link':
          tEle.addClass('btn-link');
          break;
        case 'secondary':
          tEle.addClass('btn-secondary');
          break;
        case 'cancel':
          tEle.addClass('btn-cancel');
          break;
        case 'card-icon':
          tEle.addClass('btn-icon card-icon');
          $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
          break;
        case 'content-icon':
          tEle.addClass('btn-icon content-icon');
          $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
          break;
        case 'grid-icon':
          tEle.addClass('btn-icon grid-icon');
          $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
          break;
        case 'page-icon':
          tEle.addClass('btn-icon page-icon');
          $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
          break;
        case 'link-icon':
          tEle.addClass('btn-icon link-icon');
          $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
          break;
        case 'modal-icon':
          tEle.addClass('btn-icon modal-icon');
          $(tEle).html(iconTemplate);
          break;
        case 'btn-icon-prepend':
          tEle.addClass('btn-default btn-icon-prepend');
          tEle.html($('<span></span>').html(tAttrs.text));
          $(tEle).prepend(iconTemplate ? (iconTemplate + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;') : '');
          break;
        default:
          tEle.addClass('btn-default');
          $(tEle).prepend(iconTemplate ? (iconTemplate + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;') : '');
          break;
      }
    } else {
      throw new Error('require button type');
    }
  }

  function postLinkFn(scope, ele, attr) {
    var oriTitle = attr.title;
    attr.$observe('disabled', function(val) {
      var titleDisabled = attr.titleDisabled;
      if (val && titleDisabled) {
        ele.attr('title', titleDisabled);
      } else {
        ele.attr('title', oriTitle);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainController">
    <re-button btn-type="primary" click-me="save()" id="send" text="Send"></re-button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused. There is no problem, the app is working fine. I just don't understand why it's working. Particularly, why the click event is getting triggered although ng-click="".

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. The original element you posted had `formOptions.save()` in the `ngClick` directive, so I thought you were asking why that was missing from the parsed element generated by the directive (e.g., the empty ng-click). Is your button inside a form element? If so, can you post the form tags? I would also check to make sure there's no click handler defined elsewhere in your code. If you search for usages of `$scope.sendEmail()`, what comes up?